# XML schema for recursive key-value pairs

Tags: xml, recursion, xsd, xsd-1.1

Consider the following XML sample document that holds variables with key-value pairs that can also be recursive:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<environments>
    <variable>
        <key>Variable 1</key>
        <value>Value</value>
    </variable>

    <variable>
        <value>B</value>
        <key>Variable 2</key>
    </variable>

    <variable>
        <value></value>
        <key>Variable 2</key>
    </variable>

    <variable>
        <key>Variable 2</key>
        <value>
            <variable>
                <key>Foo</key>
                <value>Bar</value>
            </variable>
        </value>
    </variable>

    <variable>
        <key>Variable 2</key>
        <value>
            <variable>
                <key>Foo</key>
                <value>
                    <variable>
                        <key>Foo</key>
                        <value>Bar</value>
                    </variable>
                </value>
            </variable>
        </value>
    </variable>
</environments>
```

I'd like to create an XML schema that can verify this structure: Zero or more `variable` elements, `key` elements are string only and `value` elements are string only or nested variables.

So far I came up with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
  xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">

  <!-- Element: Environments -->
  <xs:element name="environments">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="variable"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <!-- Element: variable_type -->   
  <xs:element name="variable">
    <xs:complexType>

        <xs:all>
          <xs:element ref="key"/>
          <xs:element ref="value"/>
        </xs:all>

    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <!-- Element: key -->
  <xs:element name="key" type="xs:string"/>

  <!-- Element: value -->
  <xs:element name="value">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="variable"/>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

This schema works for my sample document. However, I'm very unsure when it comes to the value element: `<xs:complexType mixed="true">`. This would mean that a `variable` element like this would be considered as valid as well (extra `foo` characters before the nested `variable` element):

```
    <variable>
        <key>Variable 2</key>
        <value>
            foo
            <variable>
                <key>Foo</key>
                <value>Bar</value>
            </variable>
        </value>
    </variable>
```

My question: How can I be sure that the `value` element is either another `variable` element (complex type) or just a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixed content in XSD really only works for narrative text documents. There are very few effective constraints you can impose on mixed content except by using XSD 1.1 assertions. It's best to avoid this kind of content model if you can.

Comment: I have XSD 1.1 available.
What else would you propose to achieve something like what I've shown / what I need?

Comment: One approach would be to make the content model EITHER an attribute OR a `variable` child element. That would play nicely with XSD 1.1 conditional type assignment.

Comment: I'm definitely no XML pro but it seems that using an attribute for this is improper design.
Could you provide an example of how to do this with XSD 1.1 assertions?

Comment: We've been given very little idea of the semantics that are being modelled here, but I don't see anything that suggests an attribute would be inappropriate.

Comment: Alright, a few months of more XML experience later I understand your answer a lot better - thanks :)